# Notepad++ tab bar along the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: notepad++

Is this possible?  I've spent quite a while googling and found plenty of people asking for the same thing, but no solutions.  Had a look at the list of core npp plugins, and nothing jumped out as obviously doing the job.

I'm just switching over after about 8 years of Homesite+, so tabs-on-the-bottom is engrained into me!

Seems like it should be a simple change, so I'm surprised if there's no way to do it?

Hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to move the tab bar to the bottom edge of the editor.